# Why is Ubuntu lagging so terribly on my PC

Tags: system-installation

I just finished installing Ubuntu on my PC. I was previously running Linux Mint on my device and I loved it for about a year. I decided that it was time for a change and went with Ubuntu. As I was setting up the install off of my live USB I noticed that it was lagging pretty bad. I powered through it and finished up my install. Once complete, the problem persisted on Ubuntu’s main OS. I thought that I may be having driver issues but on the additional drivers tab it says that no additional drivers are available and no proprietary drivers are in use. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

SPECS:
AMD A-10-7860k Radeon r7, 12 compute cores
AMD Kaveri/Radeon RX 580 Series
12gb DDR3 Memory

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you talking about?  If LTS do you mean with HWE or non-HWE kernel?  Also what are you comparing it to (ie what kernel was mint running, what desktop?)  I get the feeling it's hardware stack related; but you provided no details for what you installed or were using.

Comment: I am Currently running the 5.3.0-19-generic kernel running on the LTS version of Ubuntu 19.10. I was previously running the LTS version of Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.2. I am not seriously adept at any of this kind of work so I am not sure what information is needed. If any further information is needed please just ask.

Comment: @ChupacabraDFL - did you experience the same lags with Mint? What kernel were you using?

Comment: @ajgringo619 OP is running `5.3.0-19-generic`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - I meant when the OP was running Mint.

Comment: 19.10 is not a LTS release; and LTS releases have two options; HWE (hardware enablement stack enabled; 5.0 kernel currently for 18.04 but will bump to 5.3 soon) or disabled (4.15 kernel for 18.04 its whole life). HWE changes more than just kernel but the kernel version is the easy bit users usually notice. A quick look online I think mint does offer some of the HWE stack but it's not auto-updated unlike Ubuntu  (*mint allow the use of EOL kernels for 'stability' reasons letting user opt for security if desired*)

Comment: Okay I no longer know what kernel I was running on while I had mint. When I installed Ubuntu I partitioned my hard drive kind of weird though and I am not sure if that would cause a problem. In order my partitions are 1gb /boot, 12gb /root, 6gb /var, 2gb swap, 188gb /home, and a 12mb bios boot. Could that cause anything like this?

Comment: /root is the root user's directory and is not / (root) directory which I think you mean (ie. /root is the equivalent to /home/user/ if 'user' was your account).  You mentioned you noticed the issue during or pre-install, so in your position I'd download & write 19.04 to a thumb drive and 'try ubuntu' (ie. boot & use 19.04 in 'live' mode to see if the lagging is present).  That will put you on kernel 5.0 & an older stack (probably closer to what your mint 19.2 was on).. It's not a fix; but will provide clues and impacts nothing (except time, and needing thumb-drive to use etc)

Comment: I agree with your suggested course of actions. Theoretically if it is not lagging in live mode then it should work fine after installing it.

Comment: If you want a user to see a post; you need to @username (doesn't apply to you as it's your question, nor to person who wrote an answer).  If you find no lagging on 19.04; I'd suggest returning to 19.10 (ie. reboot), ensure system is fully-updated (`sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade`) then if updates found reboot & re-look for lag, if lagging is still present, I'd file a bug back on 19.10 using `ubuntu-bug linux`    (you could then install & use 19.04, but it'll be EOL rather soon so reporting the issue may help you soon anyway...)

Comment: @guiverc You were correct in your response. I installed an older build and it did not have any issues in live mode. I finished the install and it works great. Thank you for your help.